# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show - Couldn't find Article with 'id'=13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm doing Jumpstarts Blogger tutorial:

http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow

I'm trying to delete articles by adding a destroy method in my controller, however there seems to be an issue with database when actually deleting the articles. The articles are being deleted when running on my local server, but not from the database it seems?

Here's my articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    include ArticlesHelper

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        @article.save
        redirect_to article_path(@article)

    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy
        redirect_to article_path
    end
end
```

My show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article) , 
        method: :delete , 
     data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"}%>
```

articles.helper.erb

```
module ArticlesHelper

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

I've also ran the console and searched `Article.find(1)`, and it only finds the index up to 3.

I've been messing around creating and deleting articles (which is why it's up to index 13) and when trying to delete and article I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show

Couldn't find Article with 'id'=13
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `destroy` action, change the redirect to `articles_path` (plural) instead of the singular version. The singular version will attempt to look for the article that you just deleted, which of course no longer exist.

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path # pluralized the path
end
```

Comment: You deserve everything in life and more.

That worked, thanks.